# Activate or Deactivate a Session-Based Permission Set via Flow

Tags: process-builder, permissions, visual-workflow, permission-sets

I wanted to create a flow that is launched with a process builder whenever a new record is created. The user launching the flow only can create records for that object, but the flow updates a date field. I investigating whether session-based permission sets can be leveraged. I see in the documentation "You can run queries, however, do not make data or object updates in flows that also activate session-based permission sets." Is there a way around where the user can get temporary access to the object? Is creating multiple flows and launching them from the process builder viable or will I get a "DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object" error?